# Maven Nexus private repository access

Tags: maven, maven-2, repository, nexus

I have just set up a nexus repository in my local network. This repository exposes access to the Maven central repository, plus three different private hosted repositories: **snapshot**, **release** and **ext3rdparty**. All these repositories are part of the public group in nexus, which I use as a central access point for all repositories:

http://nexus.server/nexus/content/groups/public/

**My problem is**: Using NetBeans as development envirnment, I can access to all repositories **except** the **ext3rdparty**. i.e. i got a compilation error when I try to build projects which are based on libraries stored in the ext3rdparty repo, and NetBeans can't find / navigate any of the artifacts available in this repository.

I suspect this is a settings.xml / pom.xml problem and not a NetBeans one because as I said, I can access to artifacts that I've released in other repositories, but I can't figure-out what's the problem.

Here is the FULL content of my settings.xml to redirect maven to my own repository:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://nexus.server/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://central</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>

<servers>
    <server>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>***</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>releases</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>***</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>***</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

And here is the repositories-related part of my parent pom to allow deployment:

```
        <distributionManagement>
            <repository>
                <id>releases</id>
                <name>Releases</name>
                <url>http://nexus.server/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            </repository>

            <snapshotRepository>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>Snapshots</name>
                <url>http://nexus.server/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            </snapshotRepository>
        </distributionManagement>
```

Any idea of what's wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

Half of a day lost: I finally ended up with removing all dependencies from the ext3rdparty repository, uploading them again to the repository, and updating all indexes and now everything works fine...

Don't really know what was the problem here, but at least the pom and the settings were OK. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried building with Maven from command line?  Does it fail in the same way as NetBeans does?

Comment: if you login to nexus using the credentials from: <server> <id>nexus</id> <username>user</username> <password>***</password> </server> do you see the thirdparty repository? Maybe the permissions on that repo are not correct?

Comment: It could be a nexus configuration issue as well.  Can you access the contents of `ext3rdparty` repository through the browser?

Comment: Same issue while building Maven from command line (that's what NetBeans does anyways). And yes I can access the content of nexus through my browser. I'm currently looking at proxy repositories, but I don't understand why I can access to the central and not to the 3rdparty which is supposed to be part of the public group...

Comment: Yep no problem with permissions

Comment: can you execute: mvn help:effective-settings in netbeans to see if netbeans uses the correct settings?

Comment: Problem solved, see edit in my original post (can't post a self-answer untill 4 hours, stack overflow said...)

Comment: If you haven't done a full reindex, you should try that.  Removing/reuploading would do the same thing (rebuild the index).

Comment: that nice to see the problem was solved.

nexus offers 'scheduled tasks' to regularly cleanup the caches, re-index and so on. Those may prevent weird issues like this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have that sort of problem you can right click on the affected repository in the Repositories list and activate a Repair Index or Update Index and then check the status in the System Feeds for System updates.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your ext3rdparty repo to your public group?

[image: public repo configuration]